# Draw video on canvas HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to draw a video on a canvas. To achieve this I capture the onMouseDown and onMouseUp events in Javascript to get the x and y coordinates of each event (that I need to set the position, width and height of the video inside the canvas).

Therefore, every time I draw a video on the canvas, the previous I create should be stopped and the new one has to be played.
Two problems:

1) the video doesn't play (the function only draws the first frame), but his audio does

2) how can I get previously drawn videos to stop?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e3c3kore/

```
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
</body>



var canvas, context, xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd;

canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp);

function mouseDown(e) {
    xStart = e.offsetX;
    yStart = e.offsetY;
}

function mouseUp(e) {
    xEnd = e.offsetX;
    yEnd = e.offsetY;
    if (xStart != xEnd && yStart != yEnd) {
    var video = document.createElement("video");
                        video.src = "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4";
                        video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
                            video.play();
                            context.drawImage(video, xStart, yStart, xEnd-xStart, yEnd-yStart);
                        });
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e3c3kore/

Comment: [`video-canvas`](https://github.com/bfred-it/video-canvas) is a small module that links your video to the canvas and handles the drawing. You can link both videos to the same canvas and then `video1.pause(); video2.play()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) The drawImage() method was only be called once. It needs to be called once per frame.

2) Call pause() method to stop video.

For example, the follow code starts a timer loop (for drawing the frames) on mouse up and stops any previous video on mouse down.

```
var canvas, context, video, xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd;

canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp);

function mouseDown(e) {
    if (video) {
        video.pause();
        video = null;
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
    xStart = e.offsetX;
    yStart = e.offsetY;
}

function mouseUp(e) {
    xEnd = e.offsetX;
    yEnd = e.offsetY;
    if (xStart != xEnd && yStart != yEnd) {
        video = document.createElement("video");
        video.src = "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4";
        video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
            console.log("loadeddata");
            video.play();
            setTimeout(videoLoop, 1000 / 30);
        });
    }
}

function videoLoop() {
    if (video && !video.paused && !video.ended) {
        context.drawImage(video, xStart, yStart, xEnd - xStart, yEnd - yStart);
        setTimeout(videoLoop, 1000 / 30);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Using setTimeout for this is a bad idea and should use `requestAnimationFrame` instead.

Answer (score 11):

You need to set up a continuous rendering. You are only rendering the first frame of the video. Canvas is dumb and does not know about videos. You have just dumped pixels from the video onto the canvas. You need to update the canvas continuously.

The best way is to use `requestAnimationFrame` this makes sure everything is synced up with the browsers own rendering.

In the example below the rendering is started when the video is loaded. Be sure to end the previous updates if you load a second video.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canV");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var video = document.createElement("video");
video.src = "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4";
video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
  video.play();  // start playing
  update(); //Start rendering
});




function update(){
  ctx.drawImage(video,0,0,256,256);   
  requestAnimationFrame(update); // wait for the browser to be ready to present another animation fram.       
}
```

```css
#canV {
  width:256px;
  height:256px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canV" width=256 height=256></canvas>
```

Comment: an even better way is to wait for the `currentTime` of the video has changed, since rAF can fire at a higher frame rate than the video, which is approximately calculated by the browser so : either use the `video.timeupdate` event, or at starting of your loop, check if `video.currentTime !== lastPaintedFrameTime`. but anyway, rAF is best suited than `setTimeout` for this...

Comment: If you are using the mouse to drag out the video and you are rendering at the video frame rate you will get some odd effects as the mouse is updated at 60 times per second. Nor is `video.timeupdate` required to be consistent with the videos frame rate and will drop frames in favour of DOM events (like `requestAnimationFrame`) Nor is `timeupdate` synced to screen refresh, which can result in shearing. And lastly `currentTime` is not always discrete steps. having `currentTime` different from last does not mean there is a new frame available to render.

Comment: Missed the mouse position thing in OP... sorry about it, but then the best would be to set a flag when mouse is moving, no? About timeupdate dropping frames for DOM events I'm not sure about it, do you have references? and rAF will just drop frames too if browser is busy. But for currentTime, even if I do agree that different currentTimes doen't mean a new frame was painted, two identicals one means that the same frame will be painted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420724/how-to-determine-the-intended-frame-rate-on-an-html-video-element

Comment: Don't need ref for `timeupdate`.try it yourself . Best I can get on average is 4 or 5 `timeupdates` events per second, no mater what the frame rate. And I have tried everything to get some reliable method to track frames. The only way I know is to compare pixels (which is slow) . I have just spend some time testing many videos for `currentTime === lastTime`, not one showed constancy Best I got checkin at 60fps was 95 same times in 680 frames 30fps video (should have been around 680 same times), the rest had zero

Comment: When I do test with currentTime === lastTime on a 2s playing, I've got 57 saved frames, on 110 calls when 68 frames were exactly the same according to `getImageData()` which means it missed 8 same frames. But it still saved almost the half of the total calls. When I do the same test over 10s I've got similar results : 283 saved / 574 total calls where 347 were already painted. But agreed, one should not rely on timeupdate event. Ps for the tests I first created an array of canvases, drawn each frame on each canvases then did the gID checks.

Comment: FF right?. Chrome is not the same also encoding makes a dif. Most frustrating when playing to canvas is you are always behind by one frame. I use Dixie WebM decoder for Video stabilization. When I playback on canvas I have to create time code that is behind 1 frame depending how close the video time is to the render frame time.. BTW for a fuzzy frame comparison use "difference" `ctx.globalcomp..` render new frame on old, scale down and then getImageData on 32*32 pixels, Very fast. You  can compare two full HD frames testing 400 orientations, in under 2 second.

Comment: well on chrome with a webm I've got saved : 179, total : 598, same : 362. Almost the same results with mp4 and almost same results as FF. maybe something to do with OS ? Anyway, unless I really have to do some really huge operations on each frame, I'll stick with the currentTime === lastTime check, which already saves me more than the half of useless calls, but thanks for the gCO tips, I would have used something like that if I really had to check weither the frames are different or not. Here I needed to be sre they were different and didn't care about perf in the checking.