# Object to canvas javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm testing javascript on a smart TV,

I try to get an object video to canvas. With html5 video tag it works in my browser, but not my smart TV.

But when I try with an object player, I have this error message :

> Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The
> provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement
> or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'

after multiple test with (id, object id,object src..) the result is same, i don't know how i can get an Object video to a canvas.

here's a simple html test:

```
<canvas id="test" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<div id="test" style="left: 0%; top: 0%; width: 25%; height: 25%; position: fixed;">
    <object type="application/avplayer" style="width: 480px; height: 270px;"></object>
</div>
```

and the js:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const video = document.getElementsByTagName('object');
//const video = document.getElementsById('idVideo');
ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
```

Here's an example of my goal but i can't use video tag : http://jsfiddle.net/on1kh4o0/

Any idea or hack to get the same result with an object?

Comment: Maybe you need a `video` element instead of `object`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33834724/draw-video-on-canvas-html5

Comment: You can't use the video tag, because your smart TV doesn't support it? You're currently trying to use `drawImage` on a `HTMLObjectElement` type, which the error suggests; won't work.

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem is the object or not, but I'm definitely sure that you're trying to draw an array here and not the actual object. `document.getElementsByTagName()` returns an array. So you should use `video[0]` and not `video`. Unless you have multiple objects in your elements, in which case you have to use the correct index number instead of 0.

Comment: Still, documentation on `CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()` has a list of types it allows as a valid [`CanvasImageSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasImageSource) type. `HTMLObjectElement` is not one of them.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Like I said, I wasn't sure whether the object itself would be a problem or not. Just pointing out the mistake that I was sure about.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier, my smart Tv support video tag but my canvas doesn't show the video on it, if i play the jsfiddle example on the smart tv canvas is black..

Comment: These things are generally hard to figure out without a little trial and error. Go back to using the video. The example in the fiddle uses an `.ogv` source. Does your TV support that format?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier, yes i'm using smart TV samsung with Tizen (TV extension 3.0), when i'm trying with video tag, canvas still black every time without error in console log.

Answer (score 1):

You can't draw an HTMLObjectElement (`<object>`) directly on a canvas, it is not defined as a [CanvasImageSource](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#canvasimagesource).

For info, currently the only objects that are defined as being of this type are

- HTMLImageElement
- SVGImageElement
- HTMLVideoElement
- HTMLCanvasElement
- ImageBitmap
- OffscreenCanvas

And even though it's still only part of a draft specs, it is expected that [CSSImageValue](https://drafts.css-houdini.org/css-typed-om-1/#cssimagevalue) also [gets added to this list](https://drafts.css-houdini.org/css-paint-api/#drawing-a-cssimagevalue).

But HTMLObjectElement is not part of this list, and certainly will never be.

Indeed, even though you can load a video or an image in an <object>, just like with an <iframe>, you can also load a text or an HTML document or many other document types which can't be drawn on a canvas.

---

Now to your issue, as has been pointed out in the comments, you are definitely facing an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Using a video element is currently the only way to draw a video on a canvas <sub>(maybe in the future we'll be able to use the [Web-Codecs API](https://wicg.github.io/web-codecs/) too, but that's for the future).</sub>

So try to find out why your browser doesn't want to draw this video on the canvas.
Try different videos, from different sources, back in the days some Android browsers were blocking **drawing** any cross-origin mp4 video on a canvas, maybe you are facing a similar issue, if you can, try to input the video from an <input type="file">.

And if your browser has debugging tools, use them. (For instance if it's based on chromium, you should be able to navigate to `chrome://media-internals/` or `chrome://inspect` which might be bale to lead you to some logs.

But anyway, using an `<object>` as source here won't help you.

Comment: very clear answer! i'll update my thread with more details about my initial problem with video tag and canvas.

Comment: @ValentinP you could also open a new question with these details, I guess you'll not be the only one trying to draw an <object> on a canvas. This question has some value, even if an XY problem at the origin.