# HTML5 video: determine the intended framerate (fps) of a video object?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, frame-rate

If I have a HTML5 video object, I can get its properties such as `duration`. Is there also a way to get its intended framerate? (i.e. frames per second)

Note that I don't mean the actual playback rate that is attained by the browser when playing it, but the video's own native target framerate.

Or alternatively, is there a way to get the total framecount in the entire video? The number of frames divided by the duration would be what I need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the intended frame-rate on an html video element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420724/how-to-determine-the-intended-frame-rate-on-an-html-video-element)