# Which npm package can get video information

Tags: vue.js, frontend, mp4

I want to find a npm package, or a tool for getting information such as mp4 video frame rate on the front end.
Then introduce the npm package into the vue project.
This tool should look like this. It gets the address of the video, and outputs information such as the frame rate of the video (this information must be present). The more other information, the better.
I have found a map4box.js, "https://github.com/gpac/mp4box.js/". But I can't find the frame rate information I want on his official website.
So I want to ask if anyone knows about this tool.  It would be better if there is a demo code.thank you all.

Comment: This entire question can be simplified to: `Can anyone recommend an npm package to get a meta-data from a video?`. But still - such a question about "what npm package is the best" is not a good question. Please, check this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an npm package [ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg)

It can get meta from the video. Here is how - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg#the-video-object

Answer (score 2):

I would try doing it myself like shown in [this Stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420724/how-to-determine-the-intended-frame-rate-on-an-html-video-element). In my opinion an npm package would be overkill.