# How do I get the frame rate of an HTML video with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

Edit: I was able to figure this out, scroll down to the top answer to see it. AFAIK no other post on Stack (or anywhere online) with this question had a working and consistent answer.

#### Anyway...

I’m building a retiming tool for videos on YouTube and other websites, and finding the frame rate of the video element is necessary for frame-by-frame seeking and rounding reasons.

The way I’m doing it so far is by using `requestVideoFrameCallback()` and finding the smallest difference between two frame times: (sorry for bad formatting, I’m on mobile)

```js
var v = document.querySelector(“video”)
var c = 0; // time of last frame 
var framelength = 1; // length of one frame 
var fps;
function check(t, m) {
  var diff = Math.abs(m.mediaTime - c); // difference between this frame and the last
  if (diff && diff < framelength) {
    framelength = diff;
    fps = Math.round( 1 / framelength)
  }
  c = m.mediaTime;
  v.requestVideoFrameCallback(check);
}
v.requestVideoFrameCallback(check);
```

However, there are sometimes rounding issues due to the `mediaTime` having only 3 decimal places, so is there a better way to find the FPS with JavaScript?

Comment: _"How do I get the frame rate of an HTML video with JavaScript?"_ You cannot. Also you're talking about content that exists on external servers so CORS could be an issue. The only way is to check the video file's bytes, so you need a direct link to the MP4 (and PHP to avoid CORS when reading the file bytes back into JS) then check these bytes for the FPS (depends on format like MP4 or WebM or OGV).  PS: Youtube mentions frame rate in their video's page (not in embed-version), so load the page source with PHP then look for first occurrence of `"fps":`  and then extract next following 2 digits.

Comment: Well, actually I was able to tweak my code and get a consistent FPS that pretty much matched the video every time, sooo. YAY

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the intended frame-rate on an html video element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420724/how-to-determine-the-intended-frame-rate-on-an-html-video-element)

Comment: Nope, I already figured it out, check the answers for this question @Ethan

Comment: I've deleted my comment. The MediaTrackSettings method always returns 30 fps. I'm going to instead go with using mediainfo.js (https://github.com/buzz/mediainfo.js) which can actually parse the video file itself for information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a mix of some hacky `requestVideoFrameCallback` stuff, as well as making an array and rounding it, I was able to get a consistent and accurate FPS for any video. I wish I had been able to found this online when I needed it, but here it is for anybody else who had the same question as me:

#### Step 1: Set variables

- `vid` is the HTML video element
- `last_media_time` and `last_frame_run` will be used later to determine differences between frames and get the FPS
- `fps` is obvious
- `fps_rounder` is for rounding and stopping stuttering video frames from messing up the FPS, it actually contains the differences between frames, we make it have like 50 items to be sure, more about this in step 2
- `frame_not_seeked` is to stop users from moving around the video and messing up FPS, more about this in step 3

```js
var vid = document.querySelector("video");
var last_media_time, last_frame_num, fps;
var fps_rounder = [];
var frame_not_seeked = true;
```

#### Step 2: Set a ticker function with `rVFC`

We use `.mediaTime` and `.presentedFrames` to get a good `diff`, which would be either 0.016 or 0.017, assuming the video is 60fps. Then we shove it all in `fps_rounder` so we can actually have it even out to 0.016666ish so we can be sure it's 60fps and not like 59 or 61. I would recommend not trying to reference the FPS in the code unless `fps_rounder` has at least 50 items in it, just so you can be sure that stuttering won't mess it up.

```js
function ticker(useless, metadata) {
  var media_time_diff = Math.abs(metadata.mediaTime - last_media_time);
  var frame_num_diff = Math.abs(metadata.presentedFrames - last_frame_num);
  var diff = media_time_diff / frame_num_diff;
  if (diff && diff < 1 && frame_not_seeked && fps_rounder.length < 50 && vid.playbackRate === 1 && document.hasFocus()) {
    fps_rounder.push(diff);
    fps = Math.round(1 / get_fps_average());
  }
  frame_not_seeked = true;
  last_media_time = metadata.mediaTime;
  last_frame_num = metadata.presentedFrames;
  vid.requestVideoFrameCallback(ticker);
}
vid.requestVideoFrameCallback(ticker);
```

#### Step 3: Stop seeking from messing it up

As you might have seen in the above code, it references `frame_not_seeked`. This is because when a user clicks and changes the timestamp of a video, it can sometimes mess things up since `.mediaTime` is changing a lot but `.presentedFrames` is only changing by 1. So when the video is seeked, we remove the last item from `fps_rounder`, and stop the next `diff` from being added to `fps_rounder` by setting `frame_not_seeked` to false, just to be safe.

```js
vid.addEventListener("seeked", function () {
  fps_rounder.pop();
  frame_not_seeked = false;
});
```

#### Step 4: Make an averaging function

This is mentioned in step 2, so obviously we need it to exist. It's just a simple function that averages an array using `.reduce()`, in this case getting the average of `fps_rounder` and therefore an accurate FPS.

```js
function get_fps_average() {
  return fps_rounder.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / fps_rounder.length;
}
```

#### Putting it all together

```js
    // Part 1:
    var vid = document.querySelector("video");
    var last_media_time, last_frame_num, fps;
    var fps_rounder = [];
    var frame_not_seeked = true;
    // Part 2 (with some modifications):
    function ticker(useless, metadata) {
      var media_time_diff = Math.abs(metadata.mediaTime - last_media_time);
      var frame_num_diff = Math.abs(metadata.presentedFrames - last_frame_num);
      var diff = media_time_diff / frame_num_diff;
      if (
        diff &&
        diff < 1 &&
        frame_not_seeked &&
        fps_rounder.length < 50 &&
        vid.playbackRate === 1 &&
        document.hasFocus()
      ) {
        fps_rounder.push(diff);
        fps = Math.round(1 / get_fps_average());
        document.querySelector("p").textContent = "FPS: " + fps + ", certainty: " + fps_rounder.length * 2 + "%";
      }
      frame_not_seeked = true;
      last_media_time = metadata.mediaTime;
      last_frame_num = metadata.presentedFrames;
      vid.requestVideoFrameCallback(ticker);
    }
    vid.requestVideoFrameCallback(ticker);
    // Part 3:
    vid.addEventListener("seeked", function () {
      fps_rounder.pop();
      frame_not_seeked = false;
    });
    // Part 4:
    function get_fps_average() {
      return fps_rounder.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / fps_rounder.length;
    }
```

```html
<p>The FPS will appear here!</p>
<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Have fun!

Comment: Note that `requestVideoFrameCallback` is not supported in Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement/requestVideoFrameCallback#browser_compatibility This request dates back to early 2020, it has still not been added: https://github.com/mozilla/standards-positions/issues/250 It may take a while longer before either this specific feature or an alternative is added.